# create pandas dataframe from uneven data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a data set that has yearly data as well as lifelong data in python 2.7. I have a dictionary that stores lifelong data, as well as an inner DataFrame of yearly data. So it looks something like

```
Bear1
{'color':'brown',
'grown_size':'7ft',
'stats': df1}
}
```

where the dataframe 'df1' is built like the following:

```
meals      children    territory
4          5              8
2          4              6
5          2              7
```

I would like to get a dataframe that is rectangular, each row having a different years data as well as all of the lifelong stats, so this would become something like:

```
color     grow_size    meals      children    territory
brown       7ft        4          5           8
brown       7ft        2          4           6
brown       7ft        5          2           7
```

I assume that this would need something like the Series.repeat() method in pandas, although this has yet to work for me. What would be the fastest way of accomplishing this, as there are many such bears with varying ages!

EDIT
Unfortunately I found a problem with my question. The yearly data is already inside of a dataframe, not inside of a dictionary!

I have tried the following code for this:

```
 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bears['bear1'])
```

with 'bears['bear1']' being the dictionary posted above, but I am receiving the following message:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/masongardner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-        packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 226, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/masongardner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/masongardner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5158, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/Users/masongardner/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5197, in extract_index
```

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `from_dict`:

```
In [20]:
d={'color':'brown',
'grown_size':'7ft',
'stats': {2007:[1,5,7,2],
        2008:[5,3,4,5],
        2009:[5,2,6,7]}
}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

Out[20]:
      color grown_size         stats
2007  brown        7ft  [1, 5, 7, 2]
2008  brown        7ft  [5, 3, 4, 5]
2009  brown        7ft  [5, 2, 6, 7]
```

also `pd.DataFrame(d)` will also work

Comment: unfortunately through this method, I receive the following message
    
    ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: You'll need to post relevant data and code where this fails

Comment: @EdChum what about from_records ? i've fixed this index problem using from_records...

Comment: after updating pandas, I realized that my inner dictionary is already a dataframe. So I actually have a dictionary with lifelong data, and that also contains a dataframe with yearly data

Comment: You'll need to post sample data showing what your dict actually looks like, you can probably concat the dfs `pd.concat(d.items())`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Here is a simple way to have what you want for one bear.

```
# recreating your data
d = {'meals':[4,2,5], 'children':[5,4,2], 'territory':[8,6,7]}  
bear1 = {'color':'brown',
        'grown_size':'7ft',
        'stats': DataFrame(d)}


def bear_to_df(bear_dict):
    df = bear_dict['stats']
    for (k,v) in bear_dict.iteritems():
        if k == 'stats':
            pass
        else:
            df[k] = v
    return df

In [32]: bear_to_df(bear1)
Out[32]: 
   children  meals  territory  color grown_size
0         5      4          8  brown        7ft
1         4      2          6  brown        7ft
2         2      5          7  brown        7ft
```

How many bears do you have ? If you want to concatenate all your bears'data in the same DataFrame use pandas.concat

Comment: Im using 0.18.1, although I made a change to the post, as I realized I have a dictionary of values and that contains a dataframe (as opposed to a dictionary in a dictionary as stated earlier)